# How to get url?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to return Url like `/cat/prigotuvannya-yizhi/dukhovi-shafi/` where `prigotuvannya-yizhi` is category and `dukhovi-shafi` - subcategory. But can't understand, how to do it

```
public class CmsCoreDbContext : CmsDbContextBase
{
    public DbSet<CmsLiteralGroup> CmsLiteralGroups { get; set; }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    application            
        .UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.LocalizeRoutes(r =>
            {
                r.MapRoute("category", "cat/{category}/{subCategory}", new { Controller = "Category", Action = "Index"});
            });
        });
}

    public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> GetProductComparisonByListId(int listId)
    {
        var comparsionList = _dbContext.ProductsComparsion.Include(z => z.ProductsToCompare).FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == listId);
        var category = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == comparsionList.CategoryId);
        var literals = _dbContextCore.CmsLiteralGroups.AsNoTracking();

        return new ProductComparsionVM
        {
            // I need to get url here somehow
            ProductGroupUrl = "/cat/" + //"prigotuvannya-yizhi/" + "dukhovi-shafi/",
                                literals.Where(z => z.Code.ToLower() == id)
        };
    }
```

**Literals**

`CmsLiteralGroups` contain all codes, which I use in url. And I need to get it somehow

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dima, could you please help me better understand the problem? What are you struggling with? You would like to avoid string concatenation and use object model to build the url, is that correct?

Comment: @ironstone13 Yes. I don't need strings, I need to put values: name of category and subcategory. It can be different

Comment: As we dnt know what `literals` contains, im not sure this is answerable at the moment.

Comment: @Jamiec Added description about literals

Comment: Im not sure that screenshot helps that much. How do you extract category & subcategory from the code youve provided

Comment: @Jamiec, could it be that the code is a bit off, we should probably select and item by id first, and then, that item would have cat and sub-cat as properties, that we can later use to build url, is that so?

Comment: Code inside `return` don't work. It is just an example of what I want. And there is code: `r.MapRoute("category", "cat/{category}/{subCategory}" `. I need to get data from category and subCategory and with it gef full url to the product group

Comment: @ironstone13 almost certainly true but im not a mindreader so I dont know how to get those properties to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

**If** I read your question correctly, you would like to avoid string manipulation, and safely have url encoding.

**If that is what you want**, please consider using `UriHelper.BuildRelative` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`
See [UriHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Again, **assuming that we need to build a relative url**, you *could* do something like

```
        var category = "prigotuvannya-yizhi";
        var subCategory = "dukhovi-shafi";
        var id = 42;
        var result =
            new[] { category, subCategory, id.ToString() }
            .Aggregate("/", (acc, x) => UriHelper.BuildRelative(acc, "/" + x));
```

Open questions:

- What does `literals` hold? Looks like it's an object, so you would have to project it to a scalar to put into url

Answer (score 0):

Define on your `CategoryController` the ActionMethod

```
[HttpGet("cat/{category}/{subCategory}", Name="GetProduct")]
public string[] SearchByProducts(string category,string subcategory)
{
    return new[]
    {
        $"Category: {category}, Subcategory: {subcategory}"
    };
}
```

use return `Url.Link("GetProduct", new {yourCategoryString, yourSubcategoryString}` to return a new UrlLink

Answer (score -1):

String.Format is your friend, as it allows you to write out your URL in full with placeholders and pass those values in through an array.

For example

```
string result2 = String.Format("Temperature on {0:d}:\n{1,11}: {2} degrees (hi)\n{3,11}: {4} degrees (lo)", object[] { date1, hiTime, hiTemp, loTime, loTemp });
```

For more details see the official Microsoft documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___